# How do these verses match with the current world order?

Tags: politics

Check the following verses:

- [Surah Al Maidah:51](https://quran.com/al-maidah/51)

> O believers! Take neither Jews nor Christians as guardians—they are guardians of each other.1 Whoever does so will be counted as one of them. Surely Allah does not guide the wrongdoers.

- [Surah Al Bakarah:120](https://quran.com/en/al-baqarah/120)

> Never will the Jews or Christians be pleased with you until you follow their faith. Say, “Allah’s guidance is the only true guidance.” And if you were to follow their desires after all the knowledge that has come to you, there would be none to protect or help you against Allah.

The current world is not dominated by Islam. It is dominated by the Western, so-called "Rules-based International Order," with the USA at its forefront. Back then, the world was not this connected and ruled by a single power like the USA through 800 military bases. There was no NATO, UNO, or EU. Apart from military factors, there are also economic factors. The Western alliance controls the world economy. The West has the largest economy, and they control the world economy through the USD or EURO. Science and technology are also controlled by them. As a result, life-saving drugs come from the West. They are also in control of food grains, as revealed by the ongoing Ukraine war.

Muslim-majority countries are walking on a thin rope. If the Muslim-majority countries follow these verses exactly as they are, they will not survive. They will either be sanctioned, invaded, or die of hunger or disease.

The Qur'an is supposed to be a universal message applicable to the world until it exists.

So, how are these verses relevant according to today's reality?

---

What is wrong with this community?

What kind of person would DV this well-structured and well-researched question?

Comment: What, do you think Islam was the dominant religion in the world back when Muhammad was still preaching and the Qur'an was still being revealed? Do you think the early Muslims weren't surrounded by enemies on all sides? Why do you think these ayat would be any less relevant now than then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Aya does not forbid or discourage normal bilateral or multilateral relations with non Muslim individuals or states.

We may collaborate in medical issues, science, commerce and many other things.

The verse discourages to choose a non Muslim person or state as a protector, meaning as a superior in charge of protection.

Quran verses may be situational, not valid forever. There's no clear indication that these verses are bound to a particular situation, so it's advisable to stay prudent and not to rely on foreign protection.

Answer (score 4):

You quoted it yourself in your question:

> “**Allah’s guidance is the only ˹true˺ guidance.**”

Following the guidance of the disbelievers — especially to the point of taking them as guardians — just because of their military might means putting your faith in worldly strength rather than in Allah. The number of military bases one needs to effectively oppose Allah isn't specified in the Qur'an, but even 800 doesn't seem like enough to take on the all-Creator of all that exists.

There is no reason to believe that these ayat are any less relevant now than they were in the time of the Prophet; empires have risen and fallen throughout history, and Muslims have always been surrounded by enemies.

Comment: You skipped the economic factors.

Comment: @usser366312 Those are only relevant if you think bribing Allah will ever accomplish anything if 800 military bases doesn't.

Comment: Sorry! This doesn't answer my question.